# How to sort json file ascending in pymongo

Tags: python, sorting, pyspark, pymongo

I want to sort json file Ascending or Descending after connect on pymongo, and I have this problem ...

when is use this code :

```
db.data.find()

or this code : 

cars = db.cars.find().sort("price", DESCENDING)
```

I got this message :

```
<pymongo.cursor.Cursor object at 0x7f4b50315890>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can print the results from your query by iterating over the pyMongo cursor:

```
for row in cars:
    print(row)
```

`row` is of type dict and each key can be accessed in the same way that you would for a dict

To get all the dict's in your cursor:

```
res = []
for row in cars:
    res.append(row)

# Apply your custom sort function
```

Comment: i got this : File "<stdin>", line 2
    print(row)
        ^
IndentationError: expected an indented block